feel secure vs feel confident
I have a bit of a confusion with these two:
A. You should feel secure during the interview.
B. You should feel confident during the interview.
Can they be used interchangeably in this particular context or is there a relevant distintion to be made here?
If there is so, am I right interpreting them this way?:
Secure:  To not be afraid of what can happen or cause you trouble during the interview.
Confident: To trust yourself and your ability to perfom well.
Looking forward to your comments.
Thanks.

You should feel confident during the interview if you fit the positon well. You should feel secure after the interview if they quoted their salary ranges.

Secure has the sense of a person feeling safe from threats. This in football likely applies to the goalkeeper.  The goalkeeper feels secure.  It doesn’t quite apply to the striker.
Confident has a sense of a person being sure of his or her capability.  This is wider and may apply to all the players.  The striker is confident of overcoming the goalkeeper who is equally confident of eliminating any threats.
For the interview example, both confident and secure should be applicable to the interviewee.
confident during the interview
secure during the interview
Maybe an interviewee is more like a goalkeeper, fending off bombardments.

Thanks, for clarifiying. Therefore, someone might say: "I was confident and secure during the interview.

@Marcelo Martel, Yes, these two adjectives are compatible in lots of context and are usable together.  Although I can’t find an exact match for  confident and secure during the interview,  there’re other noun phrases like ‘experimental task’ and ‘change process’ that work ...

... with “confident and secure during the".

The first study named "Mental Retardation: The Developmental-difference Controversy" gave me a clearer idea about the two terms discussed here. Confident has to do more with motivation and Secured more with awareness of no threads, which is a big distintion. Thanks a lot.
